# how to use files from windows 10 in kali linux app?

Tags: linux, image-processing, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to work on some files using Linux. I have installed Kali app from windows store. can I perform the same?

I have to create a haar cascade dataset.xml for image processing . I have gone through a tutorial which was using linux environment . Should I daul boot the system. Cam I work with kaali linux app.

Comment: Kali is not the right distribution to learn Linux. It is only for experimented Linux users (interested in security). So install a newbie friendly distribution, like Debian or Ubuntu.

Comment: Then define more precisely what "working on some files" mean. If they are textual files, you could use some editor (e.g. [emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [vim](http://vim.org/), etc...). And spend several days in learning Linux

Answer (score 0):

The Kali Linux app in Windows is not a separate OS.  It is basically just a wrapper library where you can use some Linux functions on Windows.  If you want to test applications in Linux try using a Ubuntu virtual machine in Oracle Virtualbox or VMWare.